# Programmatically convert autocad file to visio diagram

Tags: c#, office-interop, visio, autocad, dwg

I am drying to convert autocad file (dwg or dxf format) to visio file. I can manually insert auto cad file in visio and then convert the cad drawing object to visio shapes. This works fine. I tried to do the same using visio interop assembly, but I cannot find any method to import the cad file. 
Is there any method using which I can import cad file to visio?
Is there any other way to convert cad file to editable visio document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the "Convert AutoCAD Drawings" addon. See here: [Viewing, Editing, and Saving AutoCAD Files in Microsoft Office Visio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa168345%28v=office.11%29.aspx).